# Manjaro: How to make taskbar icons glue to the right?

Tags: linux, taskbar, gui, user-interface

I want the rightmost icons to always be on the right of the screen. I looked through the options but couldn't find anything. Link to screenshot: http://s18.postimg.org/usvy04hl3/task_Bar.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Right click on upper panel → select Panel → Panel Preferences → Items → Move things up and down. It's basic xfce configuration.

Comment: You don't understand the problem. I can easily change the order of my items but I can't find any option for gluing my icons to the right hand side. right now, the location of the network, sound etc icons vary with how many windows I have open. I want them to instead be static, never moving.

Comment: [Try reseting your xfce panel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings)

Comment: I followed the instructions but the panel seems to only be partly reset: my icons are reshuffled and the time display has changed, but the tray icons(correct term?) are still glued the rightmost window tab.

Comment: it's a matter of customization, look at [this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-xfce-desktop) it looks like you're missing window buttons in your panel